# std::set with custom comparator

Tags: c++, data-structures, set

I am trying to order wordItems in descending wordCount order in a set.

I am in data structures, and our professor gives us challenges to use STL containers on previous assignments. The reason an std::set is being used here is because my Prof. wants to show us how to use an STL BST in practice.

I cannot seem to figure out the `std::set` and all of its functionality...

Here is what I believe to be the relevant code pertaining to my wordItem struct:

```
// header file (HashTable.hpp)
struct wordItem
{
    std::string word;
    int count;
    wordItem* next;
};

struct comp 
{
    // I have also tried bool operator<()(wordItem const &lhs, wordItem const &rhs)     
    bool operator()(wordItem const &lhs, wordItem const &rhs) const {
        if (lhs.count == rhs.count) {
            return lhs.word > rhs.word;
        }
        return lhs.count > rhs.count;
    }
};
```

And then here is my function that would actually use this set:

```
// implementation file (HashTable.cpp)
#include "HashTable.hpp"
void HashTable::printTopN(int n) {
    set<wordItem,comp> s;

    for (int i = 0; i < hashTableSize; i++) {
        if (hashTable[i] != nullptr) {
            wordItem *temp = hashTable[i];
            s.insert(*temp);
            while (temp->next != nullptr) {
                temp = temp->next;
                s.insert(*temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting an error message that says I am using undeclared identifiers. Both `comp` and `s` are causing this...
This is the exact error message:

```
HashTable2.cpp:129:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'comp' 
set<wordItem,comp> s;
             ^
HashTable2.cpp:134:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 's'
s.insert(*temp);
^
HashTable2.cpp:137:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 's'
s.insert(*temp); 
^
```

The set is supposed to contain `wordItem`'s with the largest `wordCount` first, and if two words share the same count the tiebreaker should be lexicographical order.

I feel like the issue is probably coming from the fact that I am probably not comparing these `wordItem`'s correctly

Lastly, I apologize because I assume its very messy to mix my own custom data structures with the STL structures, but any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. That should also help you rule out a few common errors yourself. Also, quote the full error verbatim, don't paraphrase!

Answer (score 0):

When you use a custom comparator `std::map` uses it as

```
comp_object(a, b)
```

In

```
struct comp {
    bool operator<(wordItem const &lhs, wordItem const &rhs) const {
        if (lhs.count == rhs.count) {
            return lhs.word > rhs.word;
        }
        return lhs.count > rhs.count;
    }
};
```

you define an `operator <`, not an `operator ()`, so it wont work.  Change it to

```
struct comp {
    bool operator()(wordItem const &lhs, wordItem const &rhs) const {
        if (lhs.count == rhs.count) {
            return lhs.word > rhs.word;
        }
        return lhs.count > rhs.count;
    }
};
```

And it will work.  This is called a functor and you can read more about there here: [What are C++ functors and their uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @NathanOliver ! I will read up on functors and their uses for sure!! However, I suppose I do not know where my issue is coming from in this case (as I am using std::set): I changed `bool operator<()` with `bool operator()()` and the undeclared identifier error remains...

Comment: @pickypoo1987: Is `comp` defined in a place where it can be found by `HashTable::printTopN`, that is, in some header file `#include`-ed in the source file where `HashTable::printTopN` is defined? Are you sure you saved both files? It's pretty hard to say anything for sure, given you haven't actually provided a [MCVE].

Comment: @ShadowRanger I struggle with the Complete and Verifiable aspects of that especially :(
However, I will change my code above to try and clarify!